# Live Channels - Query Returns Security Exception

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-tv

Aside from the unexplained Sample TV Input app (https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs/) there's not a lot of documentation on how to create a live channel in the Live Channels app.

I use a ContentResolver to insert channel info, but if I try to update this info using the update method, I get an error:

```
07-13 03:25:55.695  29194-29194/com.felkertech.n.cumulustv E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.felkertech.n.cumulustv, PID: 29194
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.felkertech.n.cumulustv/com.felkertech.n.cumulustv.SampleSetup}: java.lang.SecurityException: Selection not allowed for content://android.media.tv/channel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Selection not allowed for content://android.media.tv/channel
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:567)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1333)
        at com.felkertech.n.cumulustv.SampleSetup.onCreate(SampleSetup.java:81)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

Here's the code for the querying that does not appear to work, even after several iterations of trial and error:

```
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_INPUT_ID, info);
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NUMBER, channel.number);
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME, channel.name);
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NETWORK_ID, 0);
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_TRANSPORT_STREAM_ID, 0);
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_SERVICE_ID, 1);
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_SERVICE_TYPE, TvContract.Channels.SERVICE_TYPE_AUDIO_VIDEO);
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_VIDEO_FORMAT, TvContract.Channels.VIDEO_FORMAT_1080P);
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_TYPE, TvContract.Channels.TYPE_OTHER);
    values.put(TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_VERSION_NUMBER, 2); //TODO So I need to reset

    String[] projection = {TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_INPUT_ID, TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_SERVICE_ID};
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(TvContract.Channels.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null || cursor.getCount() > 1) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            getContentResolver().update(TvContract.Channels.CONTENT_URI, values, "'"+TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_SERVICE_ID + "' = '1'", null);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Insert new");
        }
        getContentResolver().insert(TvContract.Channels.CONTENT_URI, values);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(TvContract.Channels.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

The error seems to come about from incorrect permissions, but I think they're already enabled (and I can insert fine):

```
<!-- Required to play internet-based streaming contents. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!-- Required to register a SyncStatusObserver. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS"/>
<!-- Required to enable our SyncAdapter after it's created. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<!-- Required because we're manually creating a new account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<!-- Required to update or read existing channel and program information in TvProvider. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.READ_EPG_DATA" />
<!-- Required to update channel and program information in TvProvider. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.providers.tv.permission.WRITE_EPG_DATA" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution requires a bit of a different method of querying items using the content resolver.

Something like querying `android.media.tv` where `channel` = 1 will create a security exception, but there is a workaround based on the example code.

You can change the origin query to only include the channels that you want. For example, you can update or delete using the URI `content://android.media.tv/channel/150`